# Android | Logcat is not displaying app startup time

Tags: android, performance, logcat, app-startup

I have been trying to measure the app startup time and stumbled across [App startup time](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time). It is mentioned here that using logcat with no filters we can see the log `ActivityManager: Displayed com.android.myexample/.StartupTiming: +3s534ms (total +1m22s643ms)`. which shows the time taken to launch the process and finish drawing in display corresponding to app.

But, In my case it is not showing.

Here is the screenshot of logcat.[image: Logcat]

when launching through cmd adb via `adb shell am start -S -W com.example.app/.MainActivity`

it shows
`TotalTime: 554 WaitTime: 558`

so here what is TotalTime and WaitTime?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The metric you want is **TotalTime**, Here's the explanation of both from [this blogpost](https://www.programmersought.com/article/4459908469/) which delves into the complete breakdown of the measurement process in different scenarios:

- WaitTime is the total time spent, including the time of the previous application Activity pause and the time the new application was launched;
- TotalTime indicates the time taken for the new app to start, including the launch of the new process and the launch of the activity.

You may also want to read more about the measurement process directly from the [Android Developers documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time). To measure the initial display time, the commands you should use are as follows:

```
adb [-d|-e|-s <serialNumber>] shell am start -S -W com.android.myexample/.StartupTiming -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -a android.intent.action.MAIN
```

This will give you a sample metric that shows as:

> Starting: Intent
> Activity: com.android.myexample/.StartupTiming
> ThisTime: 2044
> TotalTime: 2044
> WaitTime: 2054
> Complete

Answer (score 1):

To find elapsed time in Android Studio, you must disable filters in your logcat view

[image]